# Click does not work in angular

Tags: angular, click

Below is the code. The click event does not work with a nav-burger and a hidden menu.

menu.component:

```
section class="hero outer is-primary is-fullheight animated slideInLeft" [ngClass]="{'is-hidden' : !menu.opened}">
```

menu.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  opened: boolean;

  constructor() { }
  open (){
    this.opened = true;
  }

}
```

header.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  providers: [MenuService],
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public menu:MenuService) {
```

header html:

```
 <div class="navbar-burger burger" (click)="menu.open()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: pretty simply open is a function therefore you need to call menu.open()

Comment: Just as it does not work ..

Comment: Look at this demo, it may help : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t56t8y

Comment: this: [ngClass]="{'is-hidden' : !menu.opened}" should look like this: [ngClass]="'is-hidden' : !menu.opened"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to bind to a property of MenuService, have MenuService emit an event:

menu.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  opened = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  open (){
    this.opened.emit(true);
  }
}
```

then listen to that event in your other component's and bind it to a local property.

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  opened: boolean;

  constructor(public menu: MenuService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menu.opened.subscribe((event) => { 
      this.opened = event;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I call it in html?

Comment: Similar to how you had it `[ngClass]="{'is-hidden' : !opened}`